# How did Ripto survive being submerged in lava?

Tags: spyro-enter-the-dragonfly, spyro-2-riptos-rage

At the end of *Spyro 2: Ripto's Rage*, Spyro defeats Ripto and submerges Ripto's body in lava.

[image: Spyro defeating Ripto]
<sub>Animated gif courtesy of [Antdude](https://youtu.be/fCXtjr0SrX0?t=168)</sub>

Despite this, Ripto somehow returned three years later as the main antagonist for *Spyro: Enter the Dragonfly*.

**Is it ever explained how Ripto survived being submerged in lava after Spyro 2?**

Comment: Plot armor is very heat resistant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's never specifically explained how he lived, just that he was found by "one of Spyro's friends".

In the [epilogue](https://youtu.be/dgTsgGa94jM?t=25) to Spyro 2, however, he's specifically called out as having lived, so this information was available before Enter The Dragonfly.

[image: Ripto in Spyro 2 Epilogue]